# ASP.NET MVC / Linq-to-SQL classes: Can I get it to infer readable display names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, modelmetadata

If I have a table `Orders` with fields `CustomerID`, `OrderID` and `OrderDate`, then the "Linq-to-SQL classes" generated class will be called `Orders`, with members called `CustomerID`, `OrderID` and `OrderDate`. So far so good.

However, if I then do `Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDate)` then the generated text will be "OrderDate" instead of "Order Date".

I tried using `Order_Date` as the field name, but that didn't work. Is there any way to get it to infer a better display name?

[I know that I can use data annotations to specify the display name explicitly, but I really don't want to do that for all my classes/members - I just want it to work by convention.]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269144/how-to-dry-up-c-attributes-in-models-and-viewmodels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method takes advantage of existing MVC 2 architecture to place conventions over the entire *For rendering methods instead of one off HTML helpers and without having to re-label everything with spaced property names.

[How to "DRY up" C# attributes in Models and ViewModels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269144/how-to-dry-up-c-attributes-in-models-and-viewmodels/2270115#2270115)

Essentially what your doing is overriding the default ConventionModelMetadataProvider behavior of MVC 2 and providing hooks for you to insert your own opinionated conventions.

Comment: @jfar: I was really hoping for something out-of-the-box, but this is the next best thing since at least it follows the extensibility path (and is preferable to doing a complete re-implementation of *For).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create your own HTML Helper for this, something like `Html.MyLabelFor`.

The rules to apply from here are up to you. You can simply split the word by case.

Comment: Agreed.  "by convention" is pretty much going to mean you have to do it yourself

Comment: Even so, the "convention" in C#/VB is to name properties using camel-casing.  For a method with the sole purpose of displaying a human-readable version of the property, I'd almost expect it to already do this.  By convention.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll mark this as an answer, even though it's not the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @James: I presume you mean PascalCase, not camelCase?

Comment: @Gary McGill Check out my answer below.  It adds your convention to the MVC 2 framework instead of forcing you to write HTML helpers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution available for your requirements contained within the answer to this question. [Asp.Net MVC 2 LabelFor Custom Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075493/asp-net-mvc-2-labelfor-custom-text).