# ASP.NET MVC 3 and Html.LabelFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I have to produce the following output:

```
<label for="FirstName">First name <span>*</span></label>
```

How can I do that using `@Html.LabelFor` helper? I don't know how to include `<span>` element inside `label` element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at this post it has what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your custom LabelFor

Please check this answer

[Asp.Net MVC 2 LabelFor Custom Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075493/asp-net-mvc-2-labelfor-custom-text)